# Does Django require an IDE an does ASP.NET require Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, django, visual-studio

I wasn't sure how to ask, but from my limited understanding and experience, interpreted languages like Python and PHP, are quicker to build and implement changes because you can do so using, well, notepad if you need to and fix something quickly.

From what I know about asp.net, you can do the same, but with a simple text editor it is very complicated to do so and using Visual Studio is just about the only way to be productive with .net.  I just remember LOTS of xml files produced automatically by Visual Studio based upon Linq, or a BLL, or whatever the current technology is (no slam there intended). I'd throw the Java stack in the same category as .NET for the purposes of this question.  I like Visual Studio but I don't like how I have to use it to recompile the whole project each time I change something in my model or controller (I'm sure that is an exaggeration but I don't know.)

Are these statements accurate?

Answer (score 1):

The need to recompile your code while using Visual Studio is due to the design of the programming language used - not due to Visual Studio.  Java is the same, whether or not you are using NetBeans, Eclipse, or NotePad.

An IDE is typically not required, but as you pointed out, it makes life easier.  I started out using vim to program in Python - but now use Eclipse.

Django comes with built-in command line tools to help you build your initial project, but in theory, you could manually create these files.

Comment: But can't you change the controller logic in Django's Python with a simple text editor and your done?  Kind of like changing something in PHP.  With asp.net/C#/Java I have to recompile unless it is the view (in asp.net mvc).  Is this true?

Comment: Python also needs to recompile (or its own equivalent) whenever you edit the source.  In the Django scenario, you need to restart the web server for this to happen or 'touch' the WSGI file if you're using mod_wsgi, although there is a workaround (http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html) which will 'watch' the files for changes and recompile whenever an edit is made.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that Python did not need to recompile its code when I did not explicitly list it. But as @hellsgate mentioned, in Django, if you wanted to see changes made to controller logic reflected, then the web server will need to be restarted if you do not have a monitoring system in place to do it automatically for you.  If you change template code, the changes will typically be seen right away.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using notepad to do your PHP work, then you wouldn't need an IDE to do Django.

That said, there are many IDEs for Django (and PHP) that can make the process easier for some.